# Java NumberFormatException when using Integer.parseInt(String arg)

Tags: java, parsing, numberformatexception

I am getting NumberFormatException when trying to parse the last part of a String to an integer. The exception prints as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "95
"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at GradeBook.parseDataToStudentArray(GradeBook.java:85)
    at GradeBook.main(GradeBook.java:12)
```

I am running a for loop to break down a long String into parts and then create objects from those parts. Here is the method:

```
private static Student[] parseDataToStudentArray(String data)
    {
        Student[] students = new Student[10];
        System.out.print(data);
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            String tempStudent = data.substring(0,data.indexOf("\n"));
            data=data.substring(data.indexOf("\n")+1);
            String firstName= tempStudent.substring(0,tempStudent.indexOf(" ")); 
            tempStudent = tempStudent.substring(tempStudent.indexOf(" ")+1);
            String lastName= tempStudent.substring(0,tempStudent.indexOf("  "));
            tempStudent = tempStudent.substring(tempStudent.indexOf("   ")+1);
            int hw= Integer.parseInt(tempStudent.substring(0,tempStudent.indexOf("  ")));
            tempStudent = tempStudent.substring(tempStudent.indexOf("   ")+1);
            int quiz= Integer.parseInt(tempStudent.substring(0,tempStudent.indexOf("    ")));
            tempStudent = tempStudent.substring(tempStudent.indexOf("   ")+1);
            int project= Integer.parseInt(tempStudent.substring(0,tempStudent.indexOf(" ")));
            tempStudent = tempStudent.substring(tempStudent.indexOf("   ")+1);
            int midterm= Integer.parseInt(tempStudent.substring(0,tempStudent.indexOf(" ")));
            tempStudent = tempStudent.substring(tempStudent.indexOf("   ")+1);
            int finalExam= Integer.parseInt(tempStudent); 
            tempStudent = tempStudent.substring(tempStudent.indexOf("   ")+1);
            students[i] = new Student(firstName,lastName,hw,quiz,project,midterm,finalExam);
        }
        return students;
    }
```

Thank you so much for any help!

I begin with a String data which if I
    System.out.print(data) 
produces

```
John Smith  92  80  86  76  95
Mary Lamb   66  89  92  100 56
Katy Perry  80  75  89  83  90
Mile Johnson    90  92  95  91  88
Jefferson Hue   75  78  70  82  73
Gabby Alden 83  79  88  94  92
Rubby Barry 89  82  75  90  86
Brian Wilson    78  83  81  89  90
Davis Brown 92  78  50  77  84
Alfred Williams 87  93  67  82  95
```

Comment: Is there some new emerging student management industry, or are computer course creators just lazy nowadays to think about more creative tasks? Ah, by the way, a problem description just stating "getting an error" won't help us to help you.

Comment: When you use your debugger, what is it telling you about the value you're passing to the Integer.parseInt that is giving you trouble?

Comment: have you never heard of `split`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suggest you use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) which returns an array. Since you have a different number of spaces between the name and first number, you can split by multiple spaces using `split("\\s+")`. For example

```
String line = "John Smith  92  80  86  76  95";
String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
```

The `split` will return

```
tokens = { "John", "Smith", "92", "80", "76", "95" };
```

The first two indices make the name and parse the rest of the indices. Since every line has the same number of tokens, it should work fine for you in a loop.

```
String firstName = tokens[0];
String lastName = tokens[1];
int hw = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
...
```

---

**Note** see @janos comment below for another option for the same functionality

Comment: I would add to replace the for loop with `for (String line : data.split("\n")) { ... }`

Comment: @janos I didn't even see that, the `data` I mean. You're right though, it would be cleaner that way.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the line break appended to the `95` confuses `Integer.parseInt` so you should clear the string of any trailing whitespaces first.